# How to get the partial email address in javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using TypeScript(Javascript)

How can I partially hide email address like this?

> jack.dawson@gmail.com to j*********n@g****.com

I am using the below script to get the above output.
But After `@` I need to get one third of the charater.
eg: If it is a 10 charcter string I need only one third of the character to be shown and remaining to be masked.

```js
let str = "tsadsadsadsadonkjhuhuhuy@gmail.com"
    str = str.split('');
    let finalArr = [];
    let len = str.indexOf('@');
    str.forEach((item, pos) => {
      (pos >= 3 && pos <= len - 2) ? finalArr.push('*'): finalArr.push(str[pos]);
    })

    document.write(finalArr.join(''));
    console.log(finalArr.join(''))
```

I am also trying to do this in php.
I prefer the output in php as well as in javascript.

I need to get one third of the character after `@` symbol before `.com`

Comment: So PHP or JS answer you are seeking?

Comment: function mask($str, $first, $last) {$len = strlen($str);$toShow = $first + $last; return substr($str, 0, $len <= $toShow ? 0 : $first).str_repeat("*", $len - ($len <= $toShow ? 0 : $toShow)).substr($str, $len - $last, $len <= $toShow ? 0 : $last);}

function mask_email($email) {$mail_parts = explode("@", $email);$domain_parts = explode('.', $mail_parts[1]);
$mail_parts[0] = mask($mail_parts[0], 3, 1); // show first 2 letters and last 1 letter$domain_parts[0] = mask($domain_parts[0], 2, 0); // same here$mail_parts[1] = implode('.', $domain_parts);
return implode("@", $mail_parts);}

Comment: I want in both js and php.

Comment: Please may you edit the question rather than posting unreadable code in the comments?

Comment: The above is my php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is JS:

```
const firstAndLast = str => {
    const firstChar = str.substring(0,3);
    const lastChar = str.slice(-1);
    return [firstChar, lastChar]
}

const firstThird = str => {
    const strArray = str.split(".");
    const result = []
    for (let i = 0; i < (strArray[0].length + 1)/3; i++) {
        result.push(str[i])
    }
    return [result.join(''), strArray[1]]
}

const str = "tsadsadsadsajhuhuhuy@gmail.com"
const strArray = str.split("@");

const [userFirst, userLast] = firstAndLast(strArray[0])

const [domainFirst, domainLast] = firstThird(strArray[1])

console.log(`${userFirst}****${userLast}@${domainFirst}***.${domainLast}`)
```

Here is PHP:

```
<?php

function firstAndLast($str) {
    $firstChar = substr($str, 0, 3);
    $lastChar = substr($str, -1);
    return [$firstChar, $lastChar];
}

function firstThird($str) {
    $strArray = explode(".", $str);
    $result = [];
    $str_length = (strlen($strArray[0]) + 1)/3;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $str_length; $i++) {
        array_push($result, $str[$i]);
    }
    return [implode('', $result), $strArray[1]];
}

$str = "tsadsadsadsajhuhuhuy@gmail.com";
$strArray = explode("@", $str);

$user = firstAndLast($strArray[0]);

$domain = firstThird($strArray[1]);

echo $user[0].'****'.$user[1].'@'.$domain[0].'***.'.$domain[1];
```

Both turn your example email into:

```
tsa****y@gm***.com
```

Comment: Your welcome.  I noticed my example above works for my@example.com domains. To also handle sub domains like my@sub.example.com.  Change the firstThird function return line to:
JS: return [result.join(''), strArray.pop()]
and
PHP: return [implode('', $result), end($strArray)];

Answer (score 1):

My simple JavaScript solution:

```js
let email = document.getElementById("email").innerHTML;

//You should validate email format before proceeding

let parts = email.split("@");
let name = parts[0];
let tld = parts[1];

let censored = name.charAt(0) + "****" + name.charAt(name.length-1)

let result = censored + "@" + tld.substring(0, Math.floor(1/3*tld.length));

document.getElementById("censored").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<span id="email">thisismytestname@example.com</span><br>
<span id="censored"></span>
```

PHP solution working essentially the same way:

```
<?php
$email = "myemail@test.com";

//Should validate email format before proceeding

$parts = explode("@", $email);
$name = $parts[0];
$tld = $parts[1];


$censored = substr($name, 0, 1) . "****" . substr($name,-1);

$result = $censored . "@" . substr($tld, 0, floor(1/3*strlen($tld)));
echo $result; //echoes t****e@example.com

?>
```

Comment: Before @ i want 1st 3 character and last 1 charcater remaining to be masked.After @ I want only one third character of string length and remaining to be unmaasked . After..com to be as it is

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't provide you with a more satisfying answer with such vage description.
Please provide examples in your question with all the requirements as you just changed two requirements from the original question.

Comment: I  want the output as "aaa**********b@one-third of the actual character.com  .Eg:If the given mail is abcxyz@gmailgamil.com means the ouput must be as "abc**z@gma*********.com

Answer (score -1):

*In PHP*

1. Extract middle parts with regex: `preg_match('\w(?<mid1>.*?)@\w(?<mid2>.*?)\.(?<ext>\w+)', $email, $matches)`
2. Replace with 1/3 of string length `str_replace($matches['mid1'], str_repeat('*'), strlen($matches['mid1']))`

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47f43370b0a7099ce83ca5e94aacd5950cdd4e50)

Comment: @Justinas Before @ i want 1st 3 character and last 1 charcater remaining to be masked.After @ I want only one third of string length..com to be as it is